# Why does the compiler invoke a templated copy constructor when assigning?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct X
{
    X() = default;

    template<class U>
    X(const X<U>&)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

/*
    template<class U>
    X& operator=(const X<U>&)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
*/

};

int main()
{
    X<int> a;
    X<double> b;

    b = a;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd91189072b5ec44)

As you can see, the assignment operator is commented out. However, the line

```
b = a;
```

compiles fine. I thought it should not compile, as `a` and `b` have different types, and the `operator=(const X&)` that is generated by default by the compiler will be instantiated by the underlying type, so it won't assign an `X<int>` to an `X<double>`.

To my surprise, the code compiles, and it seems that the templated copy constructor is being invoked. Why is this? Is it because the compiler tries first to cast the `a` to a `b` then invoke the default-generated `B::operator=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` and `U` are different types, `template<class U> X(const X<U>&)` is not a copy constructor because it's argument is of different type. In other words, `X<int>` and `X<double>` are unrelated types, so this constructor is just a user-defined conversion between them.

Note that this code won't print anything:

```
X<int> a;
X<int> b { a };
```

Because in this case the implicitly-declared copy constructor of the form `X<int>::X(const X<int>&)` will be invoked.

Comment: "Because in this case that constructor would become a copy constructor, and copy constructor can't be template." -- I can't even tell what this is supposed to mean, but a template ctor can definitely be called in situations where a copy ctor would normally be called. It's just that in this specific case, with `U = int`, the template ctor's parameter type matches that of the implicitly-declared copy ctor. If you also add a `template<class U> X(X<U>&)` ctor, you'll see that it *does* get called for `X<int> b { a };`: it may not be a copy ctor, but it's still a better match.

Comment: @hvd Why is `X(X<U>&)` called and not the default copy-ctor `X(const X&)` that's generated by the compiler? Is it because the non-const ref has higher rank?

Comment: @hvd Thanks, that was new for me. I've updated my wording.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes. The copy ctor call sees two overloads after template argument substitution: one taking `const X &`, one taking `X &`. When the argument is a non-`const` lvalue, that second one is a better match by the regular overload rules.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is generating a call to `X<double>(const X<int>&)` to convert an `X<int>` into an `X<double>`. Then it's calling the generated assignment operator `X<double>& X<double>::operator =(const X<double>&);` to do the assignment.

If you wrote out all the steps explicitly it would be:

```
b.operator =(X<double>(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

`template<class U> X(const X<U>&)` is a generalized user-defined conversion -- see Anton Savin's answer.

The rules for implicit type conversions are quite complex, so you should be wary of user-defined conversion functions ([More Effective C++ Item 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)). This is even more the case with template functions.

The code

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct X
{
    X() = default;

    template<class U>
    X(const X<U>&)
    {
        std::cout << "generalized ctor: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

/*
    template<class U>
    X& operator=(const X<U>&)
    {
        std::cout << "generalized assignment: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
*/
};

int main()
{
    X<int> a;
    X<double> b;

    b = a;
}
```

returns

> generalized ctor: X::X(const X&) [with U = int; T = double]

But for `operator=` not commented out, it returns

> generalized assignment: X& X::operator=(const X&) [with U = int; T = double].

So you are correct that the implicitly generated `operator=(const X&)` will be instantiated by the underlying type and won't assign an `X<int>` to an `X<double>`. As Scott Meyers (see reference above) explains, your compiler is faced with a call to `b.operator=` of a `X<double>`, which takes a 
`const X<double>`, and finds that no such function exists. Therefore, your compiler then tries to find an acceptable sequence of implicit type conversions it can apply to make the call succeed, [see rules in the cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). Your compiler finds your generalized user-defined conversion and converts your `X<int>` to `X<double>` to have the right argument type for `b.operator=`.